# SED email replacement (json values in an sql dump)

Tags: bash, sed

I have a database which store somes orders. In my order table, i have an "etra" field which contains all the information about the order in JSON (including users' email).
I have to dump my database. The dump works properly but I want to replace the users' email addresses with another (webmaster@random.fr in all case) for the next import of the dump.

I tried with the sed command.
This is my dump example structure :

```
(xxxxxxxx,\"billing_firstname\":{},\"billing_email\":\"machin@hotmail.fr\",\"billing_address\":\"3 avenue des salades\",\"billing_address_2\":{}),(xxxxxxxx,\"billing_firstname\":{},\"billing_email\":\"bidule@gmail.fr\",\"billing_address\":\"5 avenue des laitues\",\"billing_address_2\":{}),(xxxxxxxx,\"billing_firstname\":{},\"billing_email\":\"exemple@laposte.fr\",\"billing_address\":\"6 avenue des maches\",\"billing_address_2\":{}),(xxxxxxxx,\"billing_firstname\":{},\"billing_email\":\"test@live.fr\",\"billing_address\":\"13 avenue des endives\",\"billing_address_2\":{}),(xxxxxxxx,\"billing_firstname\":{},\"billing_email\":\"essai@caramail.fr\",\"billing_address\":\"8 avenue des feuilles\",\"billing_address_2\":{});
```

When I apply this sed with a regex:

```
sed -i -E 's/(\\"billing_email\\":\\").*(\\",\\"billing_address)/\1webmaster@random.fr\2/g'
```

The file generated contains only one order :

```
(xxxxxxxx,\"billing_firstname\":{},\"billing_email\":\"webmaster@random.fr\",\"billing_address\":\"8 avenue des feuilles\",\"billing_address_2\":{});
```

Any help with resolving this appreciated

Comment: You should avoid parsing JSON data using `sed`. Instead try to get valid JSON data from your DB and use a JSON parser like `jq` to perform the replacement.

Comment: The JSON data is valid. I export my production database to put it locally and I don't want users' emails to be present. I can't update the production db before dump, I have to edit the dump.

Comment: Well... JSON data doesn't have `(` nor `)` as object delimiter (it must be `{` and `}`. Moreover you possibly added the `xxxxxxxx` keyword, but that breaks JSON parsing. That's the reason why I say it isn't correct JSON data. If you come up with valid JSON, your change becomes trivial using `jq`.

Comment: In fact, the JSON data is in my database. When I dump the database, I have a file with a "create table" and an "insert into". In the insert into rule, the json is "encoded" to avoid interfering with the metacharacter of the sql command.

So, in my .sql I have the customers' emails in plain text and I want to replace these by webmaster@random.fr. This is not realy JSON at this moment, that's why I thought to the sed command.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you should avoid parsing JSON data with text oriented parser like `sed`.

However in this case it's just a string that looks like JSON (and isn't valid json data).

So a possible way forward is to use `sed`:

```
sed -i -E 's/(_email[\\":]+)[a-z0-9.]+@[a-z0-9.]+/\1webmaster@random.fr/g' file
```

This will replace all email address after a word finishing with the keyword `_email` by the string `webmaster@random.fr`.

Answer (score 0):

I just made some changes to your regex but your solution works !

The final command is :

```
sed -i -E 's/(_email[\\":\\"]+)[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9._%+-]+/\1webmaster@random.fr/g'
```

Thanks you for your help !